# AWS Beanstalk single instance forward 443 to 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get a single instance of beanstalk up and running. I don't see anyway to forward 443 to 80 without there being a loadbalancer. How do I get this to work? I can no longer access the application when it has been converted to a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

When using single instance the requests will hit the environments EC2 instances immediately since there is no load balancer in between. This means that the web server must be listening to 443 if you have any intention of providing a responses to requests on that port.

I'm assuming you want HTTPS enabled on this single instance environment, this can be configured using the `Resources` key in your environment configuration as explained here: [Configuring Your Application to Terminate HTTPS Connections at the Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html)